# Какие есть пути парсинга XML, поступающего из Stream, когда в нём встречаются крякозябры, которые XmlReader переводят в ошибочное состояние?

Tags: парсер, xml, c#-8.0

В XML значении атрибута встречаются символы непонятной кодировки, которые вызывают выброс XmlException из XmlReader. Как можно поступить, чтобы получить корректную строку?

Comment: Дайте больше информации. Приведите пример xml. / Возможно, проблема как раз в неправильно указанной кодировке? / Ну или нужно пинать того, кто пишет невалидный xml.